# Is there a way to convert a struct into an array without using a loop?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, struct

I'm curious, is there another way to convert a struct into an array in Coldfusion without looping over it? I know it can be done this way if we use a for in loop:

```
local.array = [];
for (local.value in local.struct)
{
   arrayAppend(local.array, local.value);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does [StructKeyArray](http://cfmldocs.com/structKeyArray.html) suit your requirements?

> Description
>
> Finds the keys in a ColdFusion
>   structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to maintain order in your structure you could always use a Java LinkedHashMap like so:

```
cfmlLinkedMap = createObject("Java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init();

cfmlLinkedMap["a"] = "Apple";
cfmlLinkedMap["b"] = "Banana";
cfmlLinkedMap["c"] = "Carrot";

for(key in cfmlLinkedMap){
    writedump(cfmlLinkedMap[key]);  
}
```

You could also do the same thing in a more "java" way not sure why you'd want to but its always an option:

```
//no need to init
linkedMap = createObject("Java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap");

//java way
linkedMap.put("d","Dragonfruit");
linkedMap.put("e","Eggplant");
linkedMap.put("f","Fig");

//loop through values
iterator = linkedMap.entrySet().iterator();        

while(iterator.hasNext()){
    writedump(iterator.next().value);   
}

//or

//loop through keys
iterator = linkedMap.keySet().iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
    writedump(linkedMap.get(iterator.next()));  
}
```

Just remember that the keys are case SeNsItIvE!

Answer (score 1):

In Coldfusion 10 or Railo 4, if you want an array of values (instead of keys), you can use the [Underscore.cfc library](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/) like so:

```
_ = new Underscore();// instantiate the library

valueArray = _.toArray({first: 'one', second: 'two'});// returns: ['one','two']
```

Note: Coldfusion structures are unordered, so you are not guaranteed to have any specific order for the values in the resulting array.

(Disclaimer: I wrote Underscore.cfc)